# How do I "hold" the randomly generated color?

Tags: python-2.7, random, lambda, colors, turtle-graphics

random_turtle_color borrowed from [this page.](https://trinket.io/python/f0a2314bf3)

```
import turtle, random
r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
print('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r()))

turtle.width(10) #What does this line do?
length = 5
for count in range(100):
    colors = (z) #I want the randomly generated hexadecimal color to be #the pen in the drawing
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(135)
    length = length + 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question led me to [faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker), a nice package to generate random data, including [random colors](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.color.html), i.e.:

```
import random
from faker import Faker
length = 1
for count in range(800):
    turtle.width(random.randint(2, 15))
    turtle.speed(200)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(135)
    turtle.left(2)
    turtle.color(Faker().hex_color())
    length = length + 15
```

---

**Note:**
`turtle.width()` - defines the size of the brush

---

[image]

Comment: I had never heard of "faker" before.  This might be very helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Neither I until yesterday ;) GL

Comment: Ok. So I am still working on this and it seems that the version of 2.7 python that I have does not include faker.  I went to GitHub and tried to download it and it seems I ended up "forking it." I'm not exactly sure what "forking it" means.  Is there a trick to downloading faker? @pedro lobito

Comment: Where do I type in pip install faker? Run command on Windows? Shell?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that.

Comment: Error messages where ever I try.

Comment: I got it. Wow. Had to install pip and then Faker. Never installed a module before.

Answer (score 1):

A key piece you're missing is telling the turtle to use the color you generated via `turtle.pencolor()`.  Here's a reworked example:

```
import turtle
import random

color_values = [random.randrange(0, 256) for _ in 'rgb']
hex_string = '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(*color_values)

turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.pencolor(hex_string)  # Set the pen color

turtle.width(10)  # Width in pixels of the lines drawn (constant)

length = 5  # Length in pixels of the lines drawn (grows)

for _ in range(100):
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(135)
    length += 5

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

You don't need to use a hex string to set the color, you can pass color values directly if they match the color mode.  Here's a rework that does that and changes the colors during the loop as well:

```
import turtle
import random

turtle.colormode(255)
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.width(10)  # Width in pixels of the lines drawn (constant)

length = 5  # Length in pixels of the lines drawn (grows)

for _ in range(100):
    color_values = [random.randrange(0, 256) for _ in 'rgb']
    turtle.pencolor(color_values)  # Set the pen color

    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(135)
    length += 5

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Is for _ in range(100): called a while loop?  And, I'm kinda wondering what '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(*color_values) does.  Thanks so much for your help. I guess I am thinking about "holding a defined variable" and using it later in a function is backwards thinking.  I can just define the variable in the function and the function automatically knows to use it?

Comment: @RickWeinberg, that's called a `for` loop, the `while` loop is different.  The `range(100)` is  way of generating `(1, 2, 3, ..., 97, 98, 99)` and the underscore `_` would normally be a variable to contain the current value but we don't care about the value in this situation, just that it loops the specified number of times.

Comment: @RickWeinberg, Python 3 introduced a new way to format strings that replaces the old `%` operator -- here's a [nice article that contrasts the two](https://pyformat.info).

Answer (score 1):

For some explanations see comments in the code below:

```
import turtle, random
r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
z = '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(r(),r(),r())
print(z)
length = 5
turtle.pen(fillcolor=z,pencolor=z,pensize=1) # pensize= width of drawed line (here 1 pixel) 
turtle.begin_fill() # Called just before drawing a shape which is to be filled.
for _ in range(100): # without '_' unused numbers are generated
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(135)
    length = length + 5
turtle.end_fill() # It's question of taste, but I like the filled figure better ...
turtle.done()     # the turtle window will stay open
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `''.format()` instead of `print()`. If you want to get a different color each time move the `z` assignment line into the for loop:

```
import turtle, random
r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
z = '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(r(),r(),r())

turtle.width(10) #What does this line do?
length = 5
for count in range(100):
    colors = (z) #I want the randomly generated hexadecimal color to be #the pen in the drawing
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(135)
    length = length + 5
```

Comment: I felt that your could was the closet to mine but it did not work.  All of my colors were black.  '###random_turtle_color###

###borrowed from this page https://trinket.io/python/f0a2314bf3 ###import turtle, random
import turtle, random

r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
z = '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(r(),r(),r())

turtle.width(10) 
length = 5

for count in range(100):
  colors = (z)
  turtle.speed(0)
  turtle.forward(length)
  turtle.right(135)
  length = length + 5'

Comment: sorry I am not familiar w/ the turtle package and didn't realize you had to set the pen color as all the other answers suggest, please go with one of them, Like @Claudio's where he uses `turtle.pen(fillcolor=z,pencolor=z,pensize=1)`

Comment: I felt that your could was the closet to mine but it did not work.  All of my colors were black.                                                                                 <!-- language: lang-python-->                                '###random_turtle_color###

###borrowed from https://trinket.io/python/f0a2314bf3 
import turtle, random

r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
z = '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(r(),r(),r())

turtle.width(10) 
length = 5

for count in range(100):
  colors = (z)
  turtle.speed(0)
  turtle.forward(length)
  turtle.right(135)
  length = length + 5'

Comment: Thank you. You might be able to tell that I am not yet familiar with Stack Overflow

Comment: I think you asked a good question which elicited a lot of good responses (with nice graphics)!